# Should I call Close() on ServiceController?

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I have a method like this:

```
    private bool IsMyServiceRunning(string serviceName)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceName))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ServiceName cannot be null or empty");

        using (var service = new ServiceController(serviceName))
        {
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way to use the ServiceController class?

The reason I ask is that all the examples I have seen do not call the **Close()** method when they're done using it. Are those bad examples or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the `ServiceController` with a `using`-statement. This will call `Dispose` on the ServiceController which is the same as calling Close() explicitly .

So in your case there is no need to call Close again.

Without the using-statement, it is necessary to call Close() or Dispose() on the ServiceController, cause it uses unmanaged resources that need to be released. Otherwise you have a memory leak.

```
ServiceController service = null;

try {
  service = new ServiceController(serviceName);

  if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
finally{
  if (service != null) {
    service.Close(); // or service.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your example wraps the `ServiceController` in a using statement, which will call `Dispose`, which will clean up the object.  It is equivalent to calling `Close`.

Answer (score 4):

`Close()` is not being called because the `using` syntactic sugar is being used here.

```
using (var resource = new Resource())
{
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
{
    var resource = new Resource();
    try
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        if (resource != null)
        {
            resource.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The automatic call to `Dispose()` cleans up the resources.

See [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/12/28/using-idisposable-objects.aspx) post for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the **close()** method again and again but i can't **dispose()** used again. The Dispose() have used the connection in database...

Comment: I have no clue why two people up-voted this. The last sentence does not make sense, and the first sentence is *false*. You can call `Dispose()` over, and over, and over and over again. The spec says that `Dispose()` must be able to be called any number of times.